# How does a reminder that has both a location and time reminder work?

Tags: reminders

I can add a reminder with both "Remind me on a day" and "Remind me at a location" turned on.

When I turn both on, how does the remind work? Is it:

1. only at the specified time if I arrive/leave the location
2. at the specific time or if I arrive/leave the location
3. something else?

Answer (score 4):

> You can be reminded when individual reminders are due, or when you arrive at or leave a location, such as an address or your car. **If you set both types of notifications for a reminder, you’re notified either at the time you specify, or when you arrive at the location, whichever comes first.**

From https://support.apple.com/guide/reminders/add-dates-or-locations-to-reminders-remnd4b206fb/mac (mentioned by duozmo in a comment)

Comment: The exact wording from official app help: "If you set both types of notifications for a reminder, you are notified either at the time you specify, or when you’re at the location, whichever comes first."

Comment: That’s too bad. I could see it very useful to have recurring reminders for certain days at certain locations. I think this could be very useful. Like having a contingency upon the location, that being a certain day or days.